# Partially filling a rectangle in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, rectangles

I have a canvas in which I want to draw multiple rectangles (of varying sizes).
These rectangles have to be filled or emptied over time, be it automatically or by input from the user.

The problem is that I have never programmed HTML5 before and don't know how to partially fill a rectangle or increase the fill (through something like rectangle.backgroundHeight++).

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="1000" width="1000" />

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

var interval = setInterval(function() {

  return function () {
    // Draw large fuel tanks
    var fuelA = ctx.rect(150, 60, 110, 130);
    var fuelB = ctx.rect(600, 60, 110, 130);

    // Draw small fuel tanks
    var fuelC = ctx.rect(40, 300, 60, 130);
    var fuelD = ctx.rect(300, 300, 60, 130);
    var fuelE = ctx.rect(500, 300, 60, 130);
    var fuelF = ctx.rect(750, 300, 60, 130);


    ctx.stroke();
  };
}(), 1000/25);
}, false);
```

Comment: for fill refer: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/ and for partial fill.. I don't know, but maybe you can use gradients see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/ .. Try changing `var grad` declaration to  to  `var grd = context.createLinearGradient(250, 250, canvas.width, canvas.height);` (Note the cange in 1st 2 arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that is possible by using one rectangle, as it can only be filled by a single color, or a gradient - and there is no option for partial fill.

However you may draw a rectangle with only strokes and no fill, and another on top of it, which acts as a fill for the first rectangle. You can size this however you want to.

**Edit:** Well it seems, you can achieve this with gradients, however I can't really tell which is the better solution.

Comment: I have tried your method and it's almost working but the rectangle seems to grow after a few seconds. I have put my code in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvep7613/1/ (It didnt show up but I fixed it)

Comment: To get this to work in jsFiddle:  Under Frameworks an Extensions, change the second select box to No wrap - in head.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I fixed it by removing the window load. It's showing up properly now.

Comment: Yep, that also does it.

Comment: It grows, because it is stuck in an infinite loop. You should limit the values of `colorAY1` and `colorAY2` according to the other box (the one without fill).

Comment: Yes but it shouldn't be growing at all. It should be getting smaller but it's not :/

Comment: It can't shrink, as you do not clear the canvas. You should clear the canvas in the interval function, draw what you want, then rinse and repeat :)

Comment: @meskobalazs Nevermind earlier comment, turns out some variables were set wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While programming the canvas is a great skill to have, an animation like this can be done completely in CSS, using [transitions](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/):

```js
var liquid= document.querySelector('.liquid');

document.querySelector('#bfill').onclick= function() {
  liquid.style.height = '100%';
};

document.querySelector('#bempty').onclick= function() {
  liquid.style.height = '0%';
};
```

```css
.tank {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.liquid {
  transition: height 3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button id="bfill">Fill the tank</button>
<button id="bempty">Empty the tank</button>
<div class="tank">
  <div class="liquid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gradient to get an effect of partially filling e.g filling a rectangle 50%.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var rec = ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 190, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "black");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
grd.addColorStop(1, "white");

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fill();

ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" />
```